# Require a solution (numerically or analytically) to a tricky trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, substitution

The integral is:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2\left ( \frac{\theta_{k}}{2} \right )dk$$

where $$\theta_{k} = \arctan\left ( \frac{4\sin{k}}{4e^{J}\sin^2{k} + e^{J} - e^{-J}} \right )$$

Is it possible to analytically solve this through substitution to obtain a solution dependent on J? If so, how would I go about solving this?
It should be worth noting that J is a constant.

Both mathematica and Python are struggling, unless I have coded wrong?

Comment: Abstracting things, you have something like $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^2 \left(\mathrm{arctan}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\alpha\sin^2 x + \beta}\right)\right) dx$. The clear thing that stands out is that $\sin^2\left(\arctan (\cdot)\right)$. If you let $t = \arctan(\cdot)$ then $\tan(t) = \cdot$ and $\sin^2(t) = \frac{{\cdot}^2}{1 + {\cdot}^2}$. So you just have a rational function in $\sin x$, which can be dealt with by standard methods

Comment: Mathematica and Python struggling is probably because it doesn't simplify $\sin^2(\arctan(\cdot))$ automatically due to things with domains and explosions... I think.

Comment: Thank you @GarethMa, does the fact that the argument of $\sin^2$ is t/2 not play a part in the solving?

Comment: It does, but you can deal with that. Just find $\sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$ instead

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, J can take any value but for now considering it to be small to the order of 10. Although won't need to approximate

Comment: @GarethMa, no matter which way I choose the integration variable (to substitute), I obtain an integral that has both theta and k in and cannot cancel either out through substitution

Comment: Interesting problem which is not obvious at all (at least to me).

Comment: I think that I have the antiderivative. I shall continue tomorrow.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici could you kindly enlighten me with what you got or please let me know how you went about it?

Comment: Mathematica for the antiderivative. Now, the problem is with the limits. I have to go now but I shall continue tomorrow. Nesty ellipric integrals for sure.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yeppp! Not the nicest of integrals for sure! The limits are messing me up too, made a substitution of u = sin^2(k), but that means the integral is between 0 and 0 - why can't it just make sense!

Comment: @purplehippo314 Your substitution doesn't work since $\varphi: [-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$, $\varphi(t) = \sin^2(t)$ is not injective.

Comment: I don't understand your original question. In particular, why do you still have $\theta$? As I showed above, you should substitute the definition of $\theta_k$ into the original $\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta_k}{2}\right)$ then simplify it using trig.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, one can see that the integrand is an even function, so the integral reduces to

$$
I = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{4\sin k}{4e^J \sin^2 k + e^J - e^{-J}}\right)\right)
$$

Define $X := \frac{4\sin k}{4e^J \sin^2 k + e^J - e^{-J}}$ and $T := \arctan(X)$. Then, $X = \tan(T)$ and so $\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}T\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - 2\cos(T)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{X^2 + 1}}\right)$ Therefore,

\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sin^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} T(X(k)) \right) dk \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{X^2 + 1}} dk \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}I_0
\end{align*}

Next we tackle the integral (help me). We abstract the constants by writing $X := \frac{\sin k}{a\sin^2 k + b}$ instead, where $a = e^J$ and $b = \frac{1}{4}\left(a - a^{-1}\right)$. We also assume that $J > 0$, which means $a > 1$ and $b > 0$. Then,

$$
\begin{align*}
I_0 &= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\sin k}{a\sin^2 k + b}\right)^2}} dk \\
&= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{(a\sin^2 k + b)^2 + \sin^2 k}{(a\sin^2 k + b)^2}}} dk \\
&= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{a\sin k + b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^4 k + (2ab + 1)\sin^2 k + b^2}} dk
\end{align*}
$$

Where in the final step, we actually used the fact that $a\sin^2 k + b > 0$ to allow extracting the square root. Finally, the final expression can be split into two integrals. The first one is $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{a\sin k}{\sqrt{a^2(1 - \cos^2 k)^2 + (2ab + 1)(1 - \cos^2 k) + b^2}} dk$, which after a substitution $t = \cos k$ and simplification gives something like $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^4 + At^2 + B}} dt$, which I doubt has a closed form. The second integral is something similar except it's 50 times worse, and it seems that one might be able to write it in terms of elliptic integrals, but I am not bothered to do so. But this form should be enough for accurate numeric approximation.

Comment: This problem is a nightmare. I have obtained the antiderivative but no way to evaluate at the upper bound.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You essentially got the same thing as me and posted it :shrug:

Comment: What is nice in that story is that today I learnt a new word : *shrug* ! First time I see or hear it. Back to serious, what is interesting is that, as long as we do not make $k=\sin^{-1}(t)$ we have the analytical antiderivative. I think that I shall put it in Mathematica SE. Cheers :-)

Comment: We have it !!! Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$a=e^J \qquad \text{and}\qquad b=\frac{e^J-e^{-J}}{4}=\frac 12 \sinh(J) $$
we have to compute
$$I=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin   (k)}{a \sin ^2(k)+b}\right)\right)\,dk$$
$$I=\frac 2{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin   (k)}{a \sin ^2(k)+b}\right)\right)\,dk$$
$$I=\frac 12-\frac 1{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\cos \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin   (k)}{a \sin ^2(k)+b}\right)\right)\,dk$$
$$I=\frac 12-\frac 1{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\frac{a \sin ^2(k)+b}{\sqrt{\left(a \sin
   ^2(k)+b\right)^2+\sin ^2(k)}}\,dk$$
Let
$$\alpha=a^2 \qquad  \qquad\beta=1+2ab \qquad \qquad \gamma=b^2$$ to write the integral
$$\color{blue}{I=\frac 12-\frac 1{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\frac{a \sin ^2(k)+b}{\sqrt{\alpha  \sin ^4(k)+\beta  \sin ^2(k)+\gamma  }}\,dk}$$

Mathematica produces an antiderivative in terms of elliptic integrals of the first and third kinds but not the definite integral integral. The problem is the evaluation at the upper bound where appear several indeterminate forms because the arguments of the elliptic integrals involve $\tan(k)$.  I let my computer running $14$ hours for no result.

Notice that using $k=\sin ^{-1}(t)$  which leads to
$$\int_0^1 \frac{a t^2+b}{\sqrt{1-t^2} \sqrt{\alpha  t^4+\beta    t^2+\gamma}}\,dt$$ Mathematica does not return anything.

I did not find any way to perform any detailed asymptotic analysis except that, for $J > \frac 12$
$$\color{red}{\large I \sim \frac{1}{2} e^{-(2 J+1)}}$$

A few numbers for $\log(I)$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
J & \text{estimate} & \text{exact} \\
 0.5 & -2.69315 & -2.64093 \\
 1.0 & -3.69315 & -3.69321 \\
 1.5 & -4.69315 & -4.71096 \\
 2.0 & -5.69315 & -5.71733 \\
 2.5 & -6.69315 & -6.71966 \\
 3.0 & -7.69315 & -7.72051 \\
 3.5 & -8.69315 & -8.72083 \\
 4.0 & -9.69315 & -9.72094 \\
 4.5 & -10.6931 & -10.7210 \\
 5.0 & -11.6931 & -11.7210 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Thanks to @Ulrich Neumann  (have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284272/a-curious-integration-problem-the-antiderivative-is-known-but-not-the-definite/284282?noredirect=1#comment707906_284282)), we have the solution for

$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{a \sin ^2(k)+b}{\sqrt{\alpha  \sin ^4(k)+\beta  \sin ^2(k)+\gamma  }}\,dk$$

and thanks to @Andreas (have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284272/a-curious-integration-problem-the-antiderivative-is-known-but-not-the-definite/284282?noredirect=1#comment707906_284282)) we have the value at the upper bound

$$\frac ab \left(2 b (a+b)+\sqrt{4 a b+1}+1\right) \sqrt{b
   (a+b)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4 a b+1}+1\right)} \times$$ $$\,\,\large\color{red}{\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\frac{a \sin ^2(k)+b}{\sqrt{\left(a \sin
   ^2(k)+b\right)^2+\sin ^2(k)}}\,dk }=$$
$$\left(b \left(\sqrt{4 a b+1}-1\right)+a \left(\sqrt{4 a
   b+1}+1\right)\right)\times $$ $$ K\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{4 a b+1}}{2 b
   (a+b)+\sqrt{4 a b+1}+1}\right)+$$
$$b \left(2 a (a+b)-\sqrt{4 a b+1}+1\right) \times $$ $$\Pi \left(\frac{2 a
   (a+b)+\sqrt{4 a b+1}+1}{2 \left((a+b)^2+1\right)}|\frac{2
   \sqrt{4 a b+1}}{2 b (a+b)+\sqrt{4 a b+1}+1}\right)$$

**Edit**

Let $b=\frac{c^2-1}{4 a}$ with $c>1$ and this simplify as
$$\frac{(c+1) \sqrt{4 a^2+(c-1)^2}}{c-1}\,\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\frac{a \sin ^2(k)+b}{\sqrt{\left(a \sin
   ^2(k)+b\right)^2+\sin ^2(k)}}\,dk =$$
$$2 K\left(\frac{16 a^2 c}{\left(4 a^2+(c-1)^2\right)
   (c+1)^2}\right)+$$ $$(c-1)\,\, \Pi \left(\frac{4 a^2}{4
   a^2+(c-1)^2}|\frac{16 a^2 c}{\left(4 a^2+(c-1)^2\right)
   (c+1)^2}\right)$$